# Unexpected Closing Bracket in R?

Tags: r, brackets, volatility

```
eCHFao<- -0.141081
#eCHFa1<-0
eCHFb1<- 0.985833
eCHFg1<- 0.199665
meanCHF<- mean(XtCHF)
eVarCHF<- (array,3421)
eVarCHF[1]<- var(XtCHF)
abco<- c(meanCHF, XtCHF1)
for (i in 2:3421) {eVarCHF[i]<- exp(eCHFao + (eCHFb1*log(sqrt(eVarCHF[i-1]))}
```

this code can't run because of an unexpected closing bracket, I am not sure why the bracket is unexpected or what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

May be a language problem since the thing that is unexpected is a curly-brace and what is missing are two closing parens (aka "brackets" in some parts of the English-speaking world):

```
exp(eCHFao + (eCHFb1*log(sqrt(eVarCHF[i-1]))
   1          2          3    4           43   # need more parens
```

The language terms referring to `(`'s, and `{`'s is a bit scattered around the world. You *should* have posted the full error message that started out:

```
Error: unexpected '}'
```

... so it didn't actually say "bracket".